# Where can I find a concordance / original text analysis and dictionary for the Apocrypha?

Tags: 1-enoch, apocrypha, resource-request

For study reasons, I would like to find a concordance for the Deuterocanonical books + the Book of Enoch. Ideally, the concordance should contain the original Hebrew, Greek and Aramaic text with an a dictionary. It should look something like this:
[KJV w/ Strong's Bible](https://www.godrules.net/library/kjvstrongs/kjvstrongsgen1.htm)
or
[BibleHub's Greek Text Analysis](https://biblehub.com/text/revelation/1-1.htm).

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an adequate concordance for the Apocrypha as of now, let alone Enoch.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the original text then copy and paste into a translator. It’s gonna be tough because it doesn’t work
Word for word in translation.

Or send the original text to translators, pay to have it done. I am very curious about some parts of that book. Man those were dark times and those giant hybrids were pure evil.

It’s says “they began to sin against the birds, fish and animals” I feel they crossbred with animals.. thus the countless Sasquatch (ape) sightings, dogman sightings(wolf) mermaid sightings and even moth man.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/48068)

Comment: @Servant king To facilitate answering the posted question, it would be better to give a location for the "translator."  (Web site, library reference, etc.)  Your comment about animals is irrelevant to the question  at hand. Peace